# Debouncing and debounced?

Tags: past-perfect

How could I express that something went through the process of *debouncing*?

Could I say "An electrical signal has been *debounced*"?

I can't find any reference that the past of *debouncing* is "*debounced*".

Comment: Yeah, it's a technical term, and perfectly OK in the proper technical context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Debounce* is a specialist term used in electronics and embedded systems. It follows the pattern of word endings used with *bounce*.

The [*Electronics glossary* at WhatIs.com](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definitions/D/page/4) references both *debouncing* and *debounced* explicitly:

[image]

The definition starts as follows:

> Bouncing is the tendency of any two metal contacts in an electronic device to generate multiple signals as the contacts close or open; debouncing is any kind of hardware device or software that ensures that only a single signal will be acted upon for a single opening or closing of a contact.
>   [- WhatIs.com](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/debouncing)

Here is another reference, stating what you're seeking explicitly:

> **debounced** *verb*
>   simple past tense and past participle of debounce
>   [- Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/debounced)